# dataset. It is giving error. "mscorlib.dll Error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Tags: vb.net

I want to show data is datagrid table rows. DATASET shows that it has found 4 record as per my query but it is giving subject error. I have to calculate data of different columns and it needs to be saved in database.

this is the complete code.

immediate help is appreciated.

```
enter code here

Dim YearTotal As Double
    Dim ArrowChk As Boolean = False


    Dim mvuserid = "Adnan"

    ' If rs.State = adStateOpen Then rs.Close()

    ' Call GET_ACTUAL_BALANCES("AAA", "2015001", "2015003")

    FgData.Enabled = True
    FgData.RowCount = 25

    Call Clear_Grid()
```

Comment: ds.Tables(0).Rows.Item Argument not specified for parameter 'index' of 'Public ReadOnly Default Property Item(index As Integer) As System.Data.DataRow'.  
this error appears in watch list...

Comment: What is `FgData`? Is that the grid? If so just set the `DataSource` like this `FgData.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)`...

Comment: yes grid. 
where should I set this...

Comment: After you call `ExecuteDataSet`. Remove everything after that as well, no need to loop the table and try to add rows to the grid when you set the data source.

Comment: i mentioned as you said and it processes the area where it was showing error. But i have some other rows and now it is giving error in end

Comment: If dr("IsOpen") Then
                    FgData.Item(23, i).Value = "OPEN"
                Else
                    FgData.Item(23, i).Value = "CLOSE"

Comment: this is the condition in last for open and close status. It is giving error on close.

Comment: I am new on VB. so i may ask silly question please bear with me and help me out.

Comment: basically we are doing calculation that is why loop is used and each row is given specific call

Comment: If it's coming from database, do the calculations there, the grid is for ***displaying*** data... Also it would prevent you from hardcoding things and hence less errors. Show your query, as you can output what you need instead of looping data that was returned.

Comment: Dear Zaggler,
Please seethe complete code.

Comment: This is not the db query, you are doing a bunch of nonsense in the grid when it can be done from the query. Also the error is because the row and or column isn't there, hence index out of range. Like I said show the query.

Comment: Dear please see the complete query processed through button.

Comment: Dear Zaggler, your kind response is awaiting.

Comment: Dear Zagglar, i am waiting please...

Comment: How many rows does your query return?

Comment: this query gives subject caption error or some time it show 2 columns and then repeat the same columns again.. Addition formula is also not working.